# operator overloading in the following program

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
Line no:29: error: no 'operator++(int)' declared for postfix '++' [-fpermissive]
```

29 |     idx2++;
|     ~~~~^~
Line no:30:9: error: no 'operator++(int)' declared for postfix '++' [-fpermissive]
30 |     idx2++;
|     ~~~~^~
#include 
using namespace std;
class index
{
private:
int value;

```
public:
    index()
    {
        value = 0;
    }
    int getindex()
    {
        return value;
    }
    void operator++()
    {
        value = value + 1;
    }
};
main(void)
{
    index idx1, idx2;
    // Display index values
    cout << "\nIndex1= " << idx1.getindex();
    cout << "\nIndex2= " << idx2.getindex();
    // advance index objects with ++operator
    ++idx1;
    idx2++;//Getting error here
    idx2++;//Getting error here
    ++idx2;
    cout << "\nIndex1= " << idx1.getindex();
    cout << "\nIndex2= " << idx2.getindex();
}
```

Finding error in line 29 and 30

Answer (score 0):

It's because you haven't overloaded the post increment operator. You need to add:

```
auto operator++(int)
    {
        auto retval(*this); // copy *this
        ++value;
        return retval;      // and return the copy by value
    }
```

Note that it's also common to return a reference to `*this` from the operator you actually have overloaded.

```
auto& operator++()
    {
        ++value;
        return *this; // return a reference to *this
    }
```